# Why Seq.take in F# throw System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: memory-management, f#, sequence

I have a code:

```
seq {for i in [1 .. 100000000] -> i} |> Seq.take 100000;;
Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : seq<int> =
  Error: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

This code results in out of memory. Why? And why exception was thrown after time calculation (after operation was complete)? AFAIK, individual sequence elements are computed only as required?

Comment: you force creation of a list before you make the sequence.  deleting the square brackets should help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
seq {for i in [1 .. 100000000] -> i} |> Seq.take 100000
```

Creates a sequence that will generate items as you ask for them, from the list `[1 .. 100000000]`. This requires the list to be in-memory. The list is too big for 32-bit memory, hence `OutOfMemoryException`. You should try

```
seq {for i in 1 .. 100000000 -> i} |> Seq.take 100000
```

Comment: Yes, i completly forget about list in seq expression.

Comment: Its somewhat interesting that the code eagerly creates the list before lazily trying to get the first 100 000 elements.  I guess the compiler would have to be exceptionally smart to skip the eager creation of the list.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci It's because of `fsi`, which begins to evaluate the seq (and even the first item of the seq requires the whole list). See @GeneBelitski's answer.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to revealing the core problem reason it may be worth addressing the second part of the question as to why the exception is thrown after the operation is complete.

For getting to understand this it would help considering that

```
let mySeq = seq {for i in [1 .. 100000000] -> i} |> Seq.take 100000;;
```

will not be followed by any exceptions, while seemingly innocuous

```
seq {for i in [1 .. 100000000] -> i};;
```

will be followed by the same exception as in original, although we seemingly do not try materializing the sequence anyhow.

That's right, we do not, but **FSI does**, trying to print out values of few first sequence members, like for a smaller list below:

```
 seq {for i in [1 .. 100] -> i};;
 val it : seq<int> = seq [1; 2; 3; 4; ...]
```

which initiates the in-memory instantiation of the original bulky list .